# Tool to open a file exclusively

Tags: tools

I'm looking for a convenient little tool that opens a file exclusively so that I can test what happens when our application tries to access it.

OS: Windows 7 and 10 (should be a Desktop application)

Answer (score 1):

There's a free utility called Easy File Locker that could work.

Find it at: http://www.xoslab.com/efl.html

Answer (score 0):

You could simply drop the file on a VBS script to lock it:

```vbs
Dim file
file = WScript.Arguments(0)

With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(file, 1, False, 0)
    WScript.Echo file & vbCr & "Press OK to close the file"
End With
```

Paste the code in a new text file and save it with the `.vbs` extension. Then to lock a file, just drop it on the script.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will lock a file when it is open. If your file can be opened by Excel and you have Excel on your system this may be an option.